# debian update-problem

Tags: debian, upgrade

When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
libc6-i386:dependency: libc6 (= 2.17-93) but 2.17-92+b1 have been installed;
```

so `dpkg` gives an error and all the updates can not continue.

If I try `sudo apt-get -f install`:

```
A copy of the C library was found in an unexpected directory:
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so'
It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation;
please remove that copy of the C library or get it out of
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' and try again.

dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.17-93_amd64.deb (--unpack):
```

I have opened the multiarch support. It's the libc6-i386 problem. Is there anyone that has seen this problem before?
What should I do?

I have searched some kind of solution which refers to chroot way, a little bit complicated. And I have checked the bug list of debian. It seems like that a long time ago someone has reported the same problem.

Comment: [see here](http://blog.i-al.net/2013/03/a-copy-of-the-c-library-was-found-in-an-unexpected-directory/) but be careful, re-moving your libc may lead to a unusable system.

Comment: Yes I have seen this before.It is a little bit dangerous so I have not done like that.Is this dependency problem comes from the upstream?Or it may caused by some other packages which installed from outside the standard source?

Comment: I guess is just some unlucky remaining passing to the multiarch (upstream).

Comment: Ok,I am ready to use the way you recommend

Comment: I think you don't need the `dist-upgrade` but the `-f install` at the end (or **better** the `upgrade` as you was looking for in the begin)

Comment: Try to figure out what's going on with : `aptitude -u`. `/libc6` ; hit `n` until you get to `libc6:i386` ; hit `v` to get the versions availables ; scroll down to 2.17-93 and hit `+`. Warning: Once a packet is in a broken state, the solver will be triggered upon every action on a packet. Also make sure that you use the same distribution (testing or unstable) on both architectures.

Comment: What repositories are you using? Add the contents of all files under /etc/apt/sources.list.d as well as the file /etc/apt/sources.list to your question.

Comment: See [this Server Fault question](http://serverfault.com/questions/486254/cant-upgrade-libc6)

Answer (score -1):

**WARNING** : *this advice could be dangerous. Keep backups, and have boot CDs handy.*

This happened to me long time ago. I recall manually editing this file:

```
 /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc6:i386.preinst
```

Search for the error message "*It is not safe to upgrade the C library in this situation*". Remove the command exit -1 in that block. Notice this check is done in 4 places. You should maybe remove all of them.

Also this file is replaced each time you run apt-get upgrade, so make a copy and after the installation process begins, put the copy over the file in /var/lib/dpkg/info/. That may take some trial and error.

Comment: I have solved this problem based on this link: http://blog.i-al.net/2013/03/a-copy-of-the-c-library-was-found-in-an-unexpected-directory/